# How to retry a command in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a command that should take less than 1 minute to execute, but for some reason has an extremely long built-in timeout mechanism. I want some bash that does the following:

```
success = False

try(my_command)

while(!(success))
wait 1 min
if my command not finished
     retry(my_command)
else
     success = True   
end while
```

How can I do this in Bash?

Comment: what do you want to do with the running one? kill it?

Comment: What does `retry` do? Do you want it to just terminate the earlier attempt and spawn a new one?

Comment: @yi_H: SO has a race condition on commenting, it seems... ;)

Comment: no, that was a `retry` *grin*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look at the GNU [`timeout`](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) command.  This kills the process if it has not completed in a given time; you'd simply wrap a loop around this to wait for the `timeout` to complete successfully, with delays between retries as appropriate, etc.

```
while timeout -k 70 60 -- my_command; [ $? = 124 ]
do sleep 2  # Pause before retry
done
```

If you must do it in pure `bash` (which is not really feasible - `bash` uses lots of other commands), then you are in for a world of pain and frustration with signal handlers and all sorts of issues.

---

> Please expand on your answer a little. `-k 70` is `--kill-after= 70` seconds, 124 exit on timeout; what is the 60?

The linked documentation does explain the command; I don't really plan to repeat it all here. The synopsis is `timeout [options] duration command [arg]...`; one of the options is `-k duration`. The `-k duration` says "if the command does not die after the SIGTERM signal is sent at 60 seconds, send a SIGKILL signal at 70 seconds" (and the command should die then). There are a number of documented exit statuses; 124 indicates that the command timed out; 137 that it died after being sent the SIGKILL signal, and so on. You can't tell if the command itself exits with one of the documented statuses.

Comment: Please expand on your answer a little. `-k 70` is `--kill-after=` 70 seconds, `124` exit on timeout, what is the `60`?

Comment: Ahhh only `SIGTERM` is sent after the positional arg duration `60`... sorry I should have spotted that. Thanks

Comment: is it possible to put this all on one line? My terminal is (obviously) not happy with `while timeout -k 70 60 -- my_command; [ $? = 124 ]; do sleep 2 ; done`.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage — hmmm; it isn't obvious why your terminal/shell is not happy with the one-liner you show.  You've got spaces in the critical places.  You don't say what error you get.  When I try it (using `sleep 5` in lieu of `my_command`, I get: `timeout: failed to run command ‘--’: No such file or directory`.  I suppose they justify that because the `60` is a non-option argument, but GNU commands usually use `getopt_long()` and permute their arguments so normally you need to use `--` to say "Do not permute arguments after this".  Omit the `--` and you should be OK (it worked for me).

Comment: The error I get is [0 is not a command, which I suspected was because the while was expecting the `;` between `my_command` and `[ $? = 124 ]` to be the one before `done`, but I just noticed I didn't have spaces in mine, so they may have actually been the issue.

Comment: Spacing is critical in shell scripts, @AncientSwordRage.  And the `[0` in the error message shows that `$?` evaluated to 0 and the shell couldn't find a program `[0` to execute because you omitted the space between the command name `[` and the first argument `$?`. — so what you typed in your comment wasn't quite the same as what you typed at your command line. You're neither the first nor likely to be the last to run afoul of this issue.

Answer (score 15):

I found a script from:
http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2014/02/retrying-commands-in-shell-scripts.html

```
#!/bin/bash
 
# Retries a command on failure.
# $1 - the max number of attempts
# $2... - the command to run

retry() {
    local -r -i max_attempts="$1"; shift
    local -i attempt_num=1
    until "$@"
    do
        if ((attempt_num==max_attempts))
        then
            echo "Attempt $attempt_num failed and there are no more attempts left!"
            return 1
        else
            echo "Attempt $attempt_num failed! Trying again in $attempt_num seconds..."
            sleep $((attempt_num++))
        fi
    done
}
 
# example usage:
retry 5 ls -ltr foo
```

Answer (score 5):

The goal can be achieved in a single line by combining `retry` and `timeout` commands - way shorter than the provided pseudocode :-)

```
retry -d 0 timeout 60 sleep 61
```

Explanation:

We chain a number of commands. Starting from the right:

- `sleep` simulates a long-running command - you'll want to replace it with your actual command.
- `timeout` runs anything passed to it, and will abort it if the command takes longer than the specified time (60 seconds in our case). You can control thw signal used to stop the process via `-s`, but the default behavior is usually good enough.
- `retry` will re-run the command passed to it upon failure. We're passing `-d 0` as its default behavior is to wait for 10 seconds between retries, which is not part of the question, so we disable it. By default, it will retry indefinitely - just like what was requested by OP - but if you want to limit the number of retries, just add `-t` with the max number of attempts, e.g. `-t 3`.

Note1: you may need to install the `retry` tool, e.g. by calling `sudo apt-get install retry`.

Note2: In case some of your command's flags clash with those of `retry`, add `--` before `timeout` to separate the arguments.

Comment: the retry command doesnt exist in my distro

Comment: @TheFool, I use it with Debian and Ubuntu (both apt based). Can't vouch for other distros though :-(

Answer (score 3):

I liked @Jonathan's answer, but tried to make it more straight forward for future use:

```bsh
until timeout 1 sleep 2
do
    echo "Happening after 1s of sleep"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapting @Shin's answer to use `kill -0` rather than `jobs` so that this should work even with classic Bourne shell, and allow for other background jobs. You may have to experiment with `kill` and `wait` depending on how `my_command` responds to those.

```
while true ; do
    my_command &
    sleep 60
    if kill -0 $! 2>/dev/null; then
        # Job took too long
        kill $!
    else
        echo "Job is done"
        # Reap exit status
        wait $!
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a command and retain control with the `&` background operator. Run your command in the background, `sleep` for as long as you wish in the foreground, and then, if the background job hasn't terminated, kill it and start over.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while true ; do
     my_command &
     sleep 60
     if [[ $(jobs -r) == "" ]] ; then
         echo "Job is done"
         break
     fi
     # Job took too long
     kill -9 $!
 done
```

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` unless you really have to. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#kill

Comment: I agree with "Don't use `kill -9` unless necessary".  Unfortunately, the http://partmaps.org/ web site seems to be AWOL now (but the Wayback Machine has it available as http://web.archive.org/web/20140123014909/http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: It's still live but the URL changed. The canonical URL which continues to work is http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Retries a given command given number of times and outputs to given variable
    # $1 : Command to be passed : handles both simple, piped commands
    # $2 : Final output of the command(if successfull)
    # $3 : Number of retrial attempts[Default 5]
    function retry_function() {
        echo "Command to be executed : $1"
        echo "Final output variable : $2"
        echo "Total trials [Default:5] : $3"
        counter=${3:-5}
        local _my_output_=$2 #make sure passed variable is not same as this
        i=1
        while [ $i -le $counter ]; do
            local my_result=$(eval "$1")
            # this tests if output variable is populated and accordingly retries,
            # Not possible to provide error status/logs(STDIN,STDERR)-owing to subshell execution of command
            # if error logs are needed, execute the same code, outside function in same shell
            if test -z "$my_result"
            then
                echo "Trial[$i/$counter]: Execution failed"
            else
                echo "Trial[$i/$counter]: Successfull execution"
                eval $_my_output_="'$my_result'"
                break
            fi
            let i+=1
        done
    }

    retry_function "ping -c 4 google.com | grep \"min/avg/max\" | awk -F\"/\" '{print \$5}'" avg_rtt_time
    echo $avg_rtt_time

 - To pass in a lengthy command, pass a method echoing the content. Take care of method expansion accordingly in a subshell at appropriate place.
 - Wait time can be added too - just before the increment!
 - For a complex command, youll have to take care of stringifying it(Good luck)
```